# Can I safely store UInt32 to NSUInteger?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c

In the header, it is defined like:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

So does an UInt32 fit without problems into an NSUInteger (an unsigned int)? Where's the difference between UInt32 and unsigned int?

And I assume that an unsigned long is bigger than an unsigned int?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose the only difference between a `UInt32` and an `unsigned int` is that a `UInt32` is guaranteed to be 32 bits long, whereas an `unsigned int` technically could be shorter if you were running (say) on a < 32-bit operating system.

However, given that the Mac and the iPhone are both at least 32-bit systems, it's safe to use `unsigned int`, `UInt32`, and `NSUInteger` reasonably interchangeably.  The only difference here is that a `NSUInteger` might be 64 bits long (on the Mac, when compiling for x86_64).

As for your question of `unsigned long` versus `unsigned int`, `UInt32` is typedef'd to an `unsigned long`, again indicating that it's safe to use interchangeably.  An `unsigned long` is guaranteed to be at least as big as an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add some environment checking code in the initial part of your program to minimize surprise:

```
 if (sizeof(NSUInteger) != sizeof(UInt32)) {
     printf("Error: Wrong integer type size!\n");
     exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: This will fail on 64-bit platforms, where `sizeof(NSUInteger)` returns 8 and `sizeof(UInt32)` returns 4.

Comment: So you know _when_ NSUInteger and UInt32 cannot be treated equally.