# Cocoa: NSUInteger and UInt32 both defined as 32 bit unsigned integer. So why the warnings?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-lion, nsuinteger

Looking in the headers, I can see that for the 64-bit system I'm compiling for, both NSUInteger and UInt32 are defined as 32 bit unsigned integers, so why is Xcode claiming a loss in precision in a warning when I assign one to the other?

"Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'UInt32' (aka 'unsigned int')"

I can see that the warning is referring to one as 'long' and one as 'int', but since they both resolve to the same 32 bit unsigned integer on this system, there should be no loss in precision.

It's not actually causing any problems, but it seems I've probably misunderstood something so would like to better understand.

There was this question, but it addresses safety as opposed to 'why':
[Can I safely store UInt32 to NSUInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753852/can-i-safely-store-uint32-to-nsuinteger)

Comment: Maybe because NSUInteger can become 64 bits long on other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUInteger` and `NSInteger` can be used even in iOS as well as in OSX.

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64 
    typedef long NSInteger; 
    typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else 
    typedef int NSInteger; 
    typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

iOS are 32 bit device whereas OSX is 64 bit(Earlier OSX were 32 bit and even you can opt to make an application for 32 bit OS), therefore it contains an `if-else directive` based on which it is set.

In OSX I always use `%ld` with `NSInteger` but in iOS it has to be `%d`.

If you use `%d` for `NSInteger` it shows the warning  Loses integer precision.

Comment: What about when you are compiling for 32-bit under OSX?

Comment: OK, thanks Anoop. So regarding how the compiler works, does this mean that it calculates warnings *before* it's resolved the if-else directive, so doesn't realise yet that it's unnecessary?

Comment: @trojanfoe: in that case it will be 32 bit, as from the if-else directive

Comment: OK, so the statement "OSX is 64 bit" is inaccurate then.

Answer (score 4):

On the 64-bit OS X platform:

- `NSUInteger` is defined as `unsigned long`, and
- `unsigned long` is a 64-bit unsigned integer.

So `UInt32` and `NSUInteger` do *not* have the same size, which explains the compiler warning.

See also [NSUInteger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW71) in the "Foundation Data Types Reference":

> When building 32-bit applications, NSUInteger is a 32-bit unsigned
>   integer. A 64-bit application treats NSUInteger as a 64-bit unsigned
>   integer.

*Remark:* 64-bit OS X uses (as many Unix and Unix-like systems) the **LP64** data model, which means that **long** and **pointers** have 64-bit. 64-bit Windows uses the IL32P64 data model, where **long** has 32-bit and **pointers** have 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm a noob at interpreting headers                  in MacTypes.h: UInt32          32-bit unsigned integer  ... typedef unsigned int                    UInt32;                              and in NSObjCRuntime.h :                                                    #if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;

Comment: @JoeyFourSheds: Yes that is exactly the place where it is defined. `__LP64__` is true on a 64-bit platform, NSUInteger is defined as unsigned long, and unsigned long has 64-bit on a 64-bit platform! - Since Uint32 has only 32-bit, you have the possible precision loss.

Comment: Thanks. (and sorry for the messy comment, can't seems to make a new line in a comment, hence it got posted about 6 times every time I habitually hit 'return'!).

Comment: @JoeyFourSheds: You are welcome. I have added a little bit information  about the size of `long`.